# VSCode does not honor editor.wordSeparators when writing PowerShell code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Previously, I had modified editor.wordSeparators to remove the dollar sign from the list of word separators, because I prefer when VSCode selects the whole variable name including the leading $ when double-clicking on a variable.

The last time I opened VSCode, it did an update and I seem to have read something about the default editor.wordSeparators value being changed for PowerShell, but I can't find anything in the release note right now.

Anyway, even though I have

```
"editor.wordSeparators": "`~!@#%^&*()-=+[{]}\\|;:'\",.<>/?"
```

in my setting.json file, it looks like VSCode doesn't honor this setting anymore as the leading dollar sign is never selected when I double-click on a variable name (e.g. $`variable` instead of `$variable`)

I also noticed that even though the hyphen is in the list of word separators, it also isn't honored by VSCode: `two-part` instead of two-`part`

Any idea why ?

Answer (score 3):

This has gone through a couple revisions in the [PowerShell VSCode Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell).

According to the [Changelog](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md):

> #### [Monday, June 21, 2021](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#monday-june-21-2021)
>
> - [vscode-powershell #3378](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/pull/3413) - Include $ in PowerShell word separators.
>
> #### [Thursday, May 27, 2021](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#thursday-may-27-2021)
>
> We now also remove `-` and `$` from the word separators by default for PowerShell files. To add them back, use:
>
> ```json
> "[powershell]": {
>     "editor.wordSeparators": "`~!@#$%^&*()-=+[{]}\\|;:'\",.<>/?"
> }
> ```
>
> #### [Friday, May 21, 2021](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#friday-may-21-2021)
>
> - ✨ [vscode-powershell #3359](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/pull/3359) - Exclude `-` and `$` from PowerShell `wordSeparators`.

So the solution is to add Powershell-specific word separators, since the editor.wordSeparators list is ignored:

```json
"[powershell]" : {
    "editor.wordSeparators": "`~!@#%^&*()=+[{]}\\|;:'\",.<>/?"
},
```

Now `Get-Process` and `$variable` are correctly selected when double-clicking on them. Happy days!